# How to add a list box which shows suggestion for codes in tkinter text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a text editor.I want to make a function which provides a list box at the position of insert ( blinking line in any editor) .Like in sublime text whenever we type something it suggest us some code or keywords to complete any word. Like this I also want a function or class to perform this action in a text widget.

Comment: This question is too broad. tkinter provides all of the necessary building blocks such as windows, listboxes, and the ability to bind to keypresses. You need to a bit more to try and solve this before coming back with a more specific question.

Comment: I am not able to do that can you tell me how to do that.I cannot place the listbox at the position of insert(blinking line) . Whenever the insert moves the box should also move.So how can I do that.